# Changing line color in Line2d - Python GIF

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, gif

I created an algorithm to solve the TSP problem. I want to present the result in the form of a GIF that shows the distance traveled. I use line2d from the Matplotlib library for this purpose. Every time the car reaches the starting point, I want to change the color of the line. I am currently using the line2d.set_color () functions for this. Unfortunately, it causes a color change of the entire road. My goal is to change the color at any given moment while keeping the previous colors. Can you help me with this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

rnd = np.random
rnd.seed()

n = 20  # numbre of clients
xc = rnd.rand(n + 1) * 200
yc = rnd.rand(n + 1) * 100
xc[0] = 100
yc[0] = 50

N = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
V = [0] + N
A = [(i, j) for i in V for j in V if i != j]
c = {(i, j): np.hypot(xc[i] - xc[j], yc[i] - yc[j]) for i, j in A}
Q = 30
# q = {i: random.choice([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) for i in N}
# q = {i: random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) for i in N}
q = {i: rnd.randint(1, 10) for i in N}

# a = [['x', xc], ['y', yc], ['Capacity', q]]
# for i in range(len(a)) :
#     for j in range(len(a[i])):
#         print(a[i][j], end=" ")
#     print()

mdl = Model('CVRP')

x = mdl.addVars(A, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
u = mdl.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

mdl.modelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
mdl.setObjective(quicksum(x[i, j] * c[i, j] for i, j in A))

mdl.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i, j] for j in V if j != i) == 1 for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i, j] for i in V if i != j) == 1 for j in N)
mdl.addConstrs((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u[i] + q[j] == u[j])
               for i, j in A if i != 0 and j != 0)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] >= q[i] for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] <= Q for i in N)

mdl.Params.MIPGap = 0.1
mdl.Params.TimeLimit = 30  # seconds
mdl.optimize()

active_arcs = [a for a in A if x[a].x > 0.99]
final_arcs = []
roads = 0
while len(active_arcs) != 0:
    temp_arcs = [active_arcs[0]]
    for i, j in temp_arcs:
        temp_j = j

    i2 = 0
    while temp_j != 0:
        for i, j in active_arcs:
            if temp_j == i and temp_j != 0:
                temp_arcs.append(active_arcs[i2])
                temp_j = j
            i2 += 1
        i2 = 0

    i = 0
    i2 = 0
    while i < len(temp_arcs):
        while i2 < len(active_arcs):
            if temp_arcs[i] == active_arcs[i2]:
                active_arcs.pop(i2)
            i2 += 1
        i += 1
        i2 = 0

    final_i = 0
    while final_i < len(temp_arcs):
        final_arcs.append(temp_arcs[final_i])
        final_i += 1
    temp_arcs.clear()
    roads += 1

plt.plot(xc[0], yc[0], c='r', marker='s')
for i in N:
    if q[i] > 0:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='b')
    else:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='y')

plt.show()
print('Liczba wykonanych tras: ', roads)

# for i, j in final_arcs:
#     plt.plot([xc[i], xc[j]], [yc[i], yc[j]], color, zorder=0)
#     if j == 0:
#         if len(colors_base) != 0:
#             c = random.randint(0, len(colors_base) - 1)
#             color = colors_base[c]
#             colors_base.pop(c)
#
# plt.show()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 200)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
x_data, y_data = [], []
ln1, ln2 = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], zorder=0)
colors_base = ['r', 'cyan', 'black', 'orange', 'm', 'darkorchid', 'dimgray', 'indigo', 'lawngreen', 'darkred']
ln.set_color('g')

plt.plot(xc[0], yc[0], 'r', marker='s')
for i in N:
    if q[i] > 0:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='b')
    else:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='y')

tmp = 0
for i, j in final_arcs:
    x_data_tmp = [xc[i], xc[j]]
    y_data_tmp = [yc[i], yc[j]]
    x_data.append(x_data_tmp)
    y_data.append(y_data_tmp)


def update(p):
    ln1.append(x_data[p])
    ln2.append(y_data[p])
    ln.set_data(ln1, ln2)
    for i, j in final_arcs:
        if yc[i] == 50 and y_data[p] == [yc[i], yc[j]] and p != 0:
            if len(colors_base) != 0:
                color = colors_base[0]
                ln.set_color(color)
                colors_base.pop(0)
    return ln,


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(final_arcs), interval=1000)

ani.save('animation.gif', fps=3)
# ani.save('animation.mp4', fps=3)

plt.show()
```

This is how the received gif looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cyeJ.gif)

Comment: Please, provide the FULL code so that we can try it. In your current question there are a whole lot of variables missing.

Comment: I modified question. Full code is enable now. I still can't solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
from gurobipy import Model, GRB, quicksum
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

rnd = np.random
rnd.seed()

n = 20  # numbre of clients
xc = rnd.rand(n + 1) * 200
yc = rnd.rand(n + 1) * 100
xc[0] = 100
yc[0] = 50

N = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
V = [0] + N
A = [(i, j) for i in V for j in V if i != j]
c = {(i, j): np.hypot(xc[i] - xc[j], yc[i] - yc[j]) for i, j in A}
Q = 30
# q = {i: random.choice([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) for i in N}
# q = {i: random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]) for i in N}
q = {i: rnd.randint(1, 10) for i in N}


mdl = Model('CVRP')

x = mdl.addVars(A, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
u = mdl.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

mdl.modelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
mdl.setObjective(quicksum(x[i, j] * c[i, j] for i, j in A))

mdl.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i, j] for j in V if j != i) == 1 for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(quicksum(x[i, j] for i in V if i != j) == 1 for j in N)
mdl.addConstrs((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u[i] + q[j] == u[j])
               for i, j in A if i != 0 and j != 0)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] >= q[i] for i in N)
mdl.addConstrs(u[i] <= Q for i in N)

mdl.Params.MIPGap = 0.1
mdl.Params.TimeLimit = 30  # seconds
mdl.optimize()

active_arcs = [a for a in A if x[a].x > 0.99]
final_arcs = []
roads = 0
while len(active_arcs) != 0:
    temp_arcs = [active_arcs[0]]
    for i, j in temp_arcs:
        temp_j = j

    i2 = 0
    while temp_j != 0:
        for i, j in active_arcs:
            if temp_j == i and temp_j != 0:
                temp_arcs.append(active_arcs[i2])
                temp_j = j
            i2 += 1
        i2 = 0

    i = 0
    i2 = 0
    while i < len(temp_arcs):
        while i2 < len(active_arcs):
            if temp_arcs[i] == active_arcs[i2]:
                active_arcs.pop(i2)
            i2 += 1
        i += 1
        i2 = 0

    final_i = 0
    while final_i < len(temp_arcs):
        final_arcs.append(temp_arcs[final_i])
        final_i += 1
    temp_arcs.clear()
    roads += 1



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 200)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
x_data, y_data = [], []
ln1, ln2 = [], []
ln, = ax.plot([], [], zorder=0)
colors_base = ['r', 'cyan', 'black', 'orange', 'm', 'darkorchid', 'dimgray', 'indigo', 'lawngreen', 'darkred']
ln.set_color('g')

plt.plot(xc[0], yc[0], 'r', marker='s')
for i in N:
    if q[i] > 0:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='b')
    else:
        plt.scatter(xc[i], yc[i], c='y')

# precompute each line coordinates
lines_data = []
xd, yd = [], []
for i, j in final_arcs:
    xd.append(xc[i])
    yd.append(yc[i])
    if j == 0:
        xd.append(xc[0])
        yd.append(yc[0])
        lines_data.append([xd, yd])
        xd, yd = [], []

# add empty lines with the specified colors
lines = []
for i in range(len(lines_data)):
    lines.append(ax.plot([], [], color=colors_base[i])[0]) 


def update(p):
    global current_line, up_to_point
    
    # reset after each animation cycle is complete
    if current_line > len(lines_data) - 1:
        current_line = 0
        for l in lines:
            l.set_data([], [])
    
    up_to_point += 1
    xd, yd = lines_data[current_line]
    lines[current_line].set_data(xd[:up_to_point], yd[:up_to_point])
    if len(xd[:up_to_point]) == len(xd):
        current_line += 1
        up_to_point = 1

# index of the line to animate
current_line = 0
# draw the current line up to the point of this index
up_to_point = 1

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(final_arcs), interval=1000)

ani.save('animation.gif', fps=3)
# ani.save('animation.mp4', fps=3)

plt.show()
```